# Snapping a square between two lines of different slope and finding the offsets based on intersection point

Tags: geometry

I need some help. I'm currently programming a game that involves 2D linear slopes for the player to move up/down on. Right now I'm working with two slopes and I'm trying to snap the player between them.

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f6XO.jpg)

The player is the square. I can't use the direct x and y coordinates of the player since they are not constant. "xi, yi" represents the point of intersection, and I'm trying to find the offsets, labeled "h3" for horizontal (x) offset and "v3" for vertical (y) offset. "ha" and "va" are the horizontal and vertical anchors of the player, which are essentially the player width/2 and height/2. "h1" and "v1" are the offsets for the first line, "h2" and "v2" for the second. I also know the angles (in degrees) of each line, though they are not marked. I've been at this for hours trying to figure it out and I can't help but feel like the solution is staring right in front of me and I just can't see it. Any help is appreciated.

Oh, and I'm trying to write algebraic equations for h3 and v3 so I can plug it into the code.

Edit: I'm looking for the lengths of lines "h3" and "v3" based on the variables shown.

Comment: The lines in the figure look perpendicular to each other. Will that be true in general or is it just an accident of this drawing?

Comment: The lines are not perpendicular, it's the drawing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you know the side length, let's call it $s$, of the square that represents the player. Note that the points of contact the square makes with the two lines have the same $y$-coordinate, and the $x$-coordinates differ by $s$. So let the points of contact have coordinates $(x,y)$ and $(x+s,y)$; this leads to the equation

$$m_1 x + b_1 = m_2 (x+s) + b_2$$

which yields

$$(x,y) = \left( \frac{b_1 - b_2 - m_2 s}{m_2 - m_1} , \frac{m_2 b_1 - m_1 b_2 - m_1 m_2 s}{m_2 - m_1} \right) $$

Then the coordinates of the center of the square will be $\left( x+\frac{s}{2},y+\frac{s}{2} \right)$, and finally the distances you want will be

$$h_3 = \frac{b_1 - b_2 - m_2 s}{m_2 - m_1} + \frac{s}{2} - x_i \\[2mm]$$
and
$$y_3 = \frac{m_2 b_1 - m_1 b_2 - m_1 m_2 s}{m_2 - m_1} + \frac{s}{2} - y_i$$

Also note that depending on the slopes of the two lines, $h_3$ might end up being negative, so if you're really wanting distance (rather than displacement, i.e.directed distance) then you would need an absolute-value around that expression.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!!! I've been at this literally all day. I was just looking at it from the wrong perspective I guess. I'll have to put all this into code and see if it works. Again, thank you! :)

Comment: Quick question though: How did you go about getting the equation for y (for the point of contact)?

Comment: Just plug the expression for $x$ into one of the two line equations; the way I set it up the left line (with $m_1$ and $b_1$) would be simpler, but both should yield the same answer.

Comment: Okay that's what I thought, thanks!